# How to resolve 502 and 503 errors with tomcat and springboot

Tags: spring-boot, apache, tomcat9

We are constantly getting 502 and 503 errors during load test. 10% errors during the test and all of them are 502 and 503. We are using apache webserver and tomcat 9 as application server with springboot as framework. Any specific configuration to be added to avoid these errors? Please let me know. PFB the tomcat connector configurations:

```
port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
maxPostSize="6291456"
maxConnections="1500"
maxThreads="1500"
redirectPort="8443"
```

Comment: I would say that you have an overload on the server. Probably the thread pool of Tomcat is to small

Comment: We tried different range of maxThreads size like 500,1000 and 1500 but nothing seems to work

Comment: Do you monitor the server during the load tests?

Comment: Yes..We dont see any high usage on threads or memory

Comment: And you also don't see any exception or errors in the logs

Comment: On logs the error is  proxy-error-502-the-proxy-server-received-an-invalid-response-from-an-upstream server

Comment: and in Tomcat? Is there an error?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i dont see any errors on tomcat logs